# MSAccess: Write one value to multiple records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a form with multiple records. The records come from a query, the criteria for the query conversely comes from the form. So far, so good. Works just fine.

Now I have a textbox (*tbx_Uebergabe_Std*) in the header and want its value to be written to a certain field (*Uebergabe_SS*) of **all** the shown records when a command button is being clicked (*cbt_Ubergabe*). What I have tried:

`Private Sub cbt_Ubergabe_Click()
    Me.Uebergabe_SS.Value = Me.tbx_Uebergabe_Std.Value
End Sub`

This is only going to change the value of the topmost record. The problem here might be that the text field for showing the value from the record is named the same the field itself.

So I thought I could directly write to the records from the query (*qry_Dose*) via:

`Public Sub cbt_Ubergabe_Click()
    qry_Dose.Uebergabe_SS.Value = Me.tbx_Uebergabe_Std.Value
End Sub`

But this is only causing a runtime error (424, if you want to know.).

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the forms `.RecordsetClone` property to iterate through all items:

```
Public Sub cbt_Ubergabe_Click()
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            .Edit
            !Uebergabe_SS.Value = Me.tbx_Uebergabe_Std.Value
            .Update
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this might cause locking conflicts. You can try using `.Recordset` to avoid them, but then you'll be visibly moving through all items on the form.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "locking conflicts". But this just works fine. Thank you Erik!

Comment: If you're editing an item on the form, this code will attempt to edit that same item as well. That's a conflict, since one row can't be edited in two ways at the same time, which might cause an error. If it doesn't (that depends on the forms _RecordLocks_ property, among other things), that's just fine.